# How to build own custom drag n drop template in MailChimp?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailchimp-api-v3

I want to build my own custom drag and drop templates using MailChimp template language. I didn't find any document or guide related to this. Is it possible to build a custom drag and drop templates in mailchimp? Please help me out with this issue. If you have any idea regarding this please let me know.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to create a drag-and-drop template on Mailchimp. However, you can create code a HTML template and use Mailchimp's email template language to make certain blocks editable (text, images, etc.)

You can find more info on how to do this in the [Mailchimp API Documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/templates/add-template/) and check out this [article from Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/help/getting-started-with-mailchimps-template-language/) on the template language.